# Cómo realizar busqueda en mysql con select box PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php7

No me realiza la busqueda al seleccionar 3 selectbox de un formulario quiero que me muestre los resultados con las 3 coincidencias seleccionadas en la tabla y me manda el siguiente error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in C:\wamp64\www".

He leído la Documentación en https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php pero aún no me queda claro que estoy haciendo mal, ya que "$resultados= $mysqli->query($sql);" lo estoy declarando de la forma correcta. AGRADEZCO SU AYUDA

Formulario Busqueda:

```
<?php
$query=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT clave, categoria_tatuaje FROM 
categoria_tatuaje");
$query2=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT clave, ubicacion_tatuaje FROM 
ubicacion_tatuaje");
$query3=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT clave, medio_identificacion FROM 
medios_identificacion");
?>

<select name="categoria_tatuaje" id="categoria_tatuaje" class='form-control' 
>
                <?php 
                    while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                    {
                ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo 
    $datos['categoria_tatuaje']?>"> <?php echo $datos['categoria_tatuaje']?> 
    </option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?> 
 </select>

 <select name="ubicacion_tatuaje" id="ubicacion_tatuaje" class='form- 
 control'>
              <?php 
                  while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($query2))
                    {
                ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo 
  $datos['ubicacion_tatuaje']?>"> <?php echo $datos['ubicacion_tatuaje']?> 
  </option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?> 
</select>

<select name="medios_identificacion" id="medios_identificacion" class='form- 
 control'>
               <?php 
                  while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($query3))
                    {
                ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo 
  $datos['medio_identificacion']?>"> <?php echo 
  $datos['medio_identificacion']?> </option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
</select>

<center><button name="buscar" type="submit" class="btn btn- 
info">BUSCAR</button></center><br>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Código PHP para realizar consultas...busqueda_reincidenciaDos.php

```
  <?php
  include 'conexion.php';
  $consulta="";

  if(isset($_GET['categoria_tatuaje']) AND 
  $_GET['categoria_tatuaje']!="Cualquiera"){
  $consulta  ="categoria_tatuaje LIKE '%".$_GET['categoria_tatuaje']."%' AND 
  ";
  }
  if(isset($_GET['ubicacion_tatuaje']) AND 
  $_GET['barrio']!="ubicacion_tatuaje"){
  $consulta .= "ubicacion_tatuaje LIKE '%".$_GET['ubicacion_tatuaje']."%' 
  AND ";
  }
 if(isset($_GET['medios_identificacion']) AND 
 $_GET['medios_identificacion']!="Cualquiera"){
 $consulta .="medios_identificacion like 
 '%".$_GET['medios_identificacion']."%' AND ";
 }
 if($consulta !=""){
 $consulta=substr($consulta,0,(strlen($consulta)-3));
 }
 $sql    = "SELECT * FROM registros_delincuentes WHERE $consulta ORDER BY 
 id_registro ASC"; 
 $resultados= $mysqli->query($sql);
 ?>

  <tbody>
        <?php while($row = $resultados->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['folio']; ?></td>
            .
            .
          </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </tbody>
```

Lo que trato de hacer es algo similar a un filtro de busqueda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me ha servido cambiar la consulta sql, sustituyendo sql con selección de 
todos los campos.

```
$sql    = "SELECT 'cada uno de los campos de la tabla' ORDER BY id_registro ASC ";
```

Comment: Si anteriormente estabas seleccionando todos los registros de la tabla mediante: "SELECT * FROM registros_delincuentes WHERE $consulta ORDER BY 
 id_registro ASC", esta modificación que realizaste no implica en realidad un cambio.

Comment: Aunque ya me muestre los resultados de los datos?